# ¿Cómo crear un reloj "countdown" para que termine en la hora de un pais en específico?

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de crear una cuenta atrás y quiero que acabe en una hora de un país en específico en este caso quiero que acabe el 31 de octubre de 2020 a las 00:00:00 hora local de Japón

Este es mi código:

```
var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 31, 2020 12:00:00").getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate - now;
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  if (days === 60){//Si ya pasaron 60 días se muestra el contador 
   $('.text').remove();//elimina un div en especifico que muestra un texto para mostrar la cuenta atrás
   document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = days;
   document.getElementById('hors').innerHTML = hours;
   document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = minutes;
   document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;
  }else{ //esta parte es para pruebas 
  }
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    //si finaliza la cuenta atras aqui se puede ocultar el contador 
  }
}, 2000);
```

¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Comment: ¿La idea es poder crear una "fecha" para un uso horario o un país específico? ¿Tiene o no que tener en cuenta la fecha y hora de la computadora donde se ejecuta?

Answer (score 12):

Para lograrlo hay que tomar en cuenta los conceptos básicos del manejo de datos de tipo [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) en Javascript.

De la documentación tenemos:

> Crea un instancia del Objeto `Date` que representa un instante en el tiempo en un formato independiente de la plataforma. Los objetos `Date` contienen un `Number` que representa los milisegundos transcurridos desde el 1 de Enero de 1970 UTC.

Esto significa que independientemente de la plataforma y de la zona horaria de la misma, un objeto `Date` tendrá siempre el mismo valor almacenado, ya sea creado en Japón, o en México o en cualquier otro lugar.

Sin embargo, cuando desplegamos su valor, el mismo será mostrado en la zona horaria y en el formato de la plataforma en la que sea desplegado.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```js
let fecha = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');
console.log(fecha);
console.log(fecha.toString());
console.log(fecha.toUTCString()); // Sun, 17 Dec 1995 02:24:00 GMT
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Dependiendo de la zona horaria en la que se encuentre el cliente que ejecute este script, los valores mostrados serán diferentes. He colocado el valor que me muestra en mi equipo para la última salida, y es que mi zona horaria actual es GMT+1. Por lo tanto el valor de `toUTCString()` devuelto restará una hora a la generada en mi sistema cuando se crea la fecha.

Ahora tu deseas generar un objeto `Date` que corresponda con la fecha:

> 31 de octubre de 2020 a las 00:00:00 hora local de Japón

Pero en tu código escribes:

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 31, 2020 12:00:00").getTime();
var fecha = new Date("Oct 31, 2020 12:00:00");

console.log(countDownDate);
console.log(fecha.toUTCString()); // Sat, 31 Oct 2020 11:00:00 GMT
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Nuevamente he puesto en comentario el valor devuelto en mi sistema de la fecha devuelta usando `toUTCString()`. Puedes observar que la fecha es 31 de Octubre de 2020, pero la hora es 11:00:00 GMT.

Dado que la zona horaria de Japón es GMT+9, debemos sumarle 9 horas a este valor para saber la hora de Japón que corresponde con las 11 horas GMT. Lo cual nos dice que esa fecha creada corresponde a las 20:00:00 hora de Japón. Lo cual es diferente de lo que tu deseas.

**¿Cómo genero una fecha con hora local de un país X?**

El constructor del objeto `Date` recibe diferentes parámetros:

- Sin parámetros: el objeto creado representa la fecha y hora local del sistema.
- Valor de tiempo o número de `timestamp`: un valor entero que representa la cantidad de milisegundos transcurridos desde el 1 de Enero de 1970 a las 00:00:00 UTC (GMT)
- Cadena `timestamp`: una cadena que representa una fecha, especificada en un formato reconocido por el método [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).
- Valores de fecha y hora como componentes individuales: Dado al menos el año y el mes, esta forma de usar `Date()`, genera un objeto que representa la fecha y horas pasados como componentes individuales, si se omite alguno (diferente de año y mes), los valores por defecto serán todos 0, excepto el día que tomará el valor de 1.

Ya sabemos los posibles parámetros que recibe el constructor `Date()`, y de estos nos interesa específicamente la *Cadena `timestamp`*.

Podemos usar uno de los siguientes 2 formatos estándar:

1. [IETF-compliant RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14)
2. [ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)

Si leemos con detenimiento la documentación de ambos, vemos que se puede indicar la zona horaria en la cadena.

Dado que Japón usa la zona horaria [GMT+9](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huso_horario#UTC.2B09:00.2C_I), una forma en la que podemos escribir la cadena indicando la zona horaria de Japón sería la siguiente:

1. IETF-compliant RFC 2822: `'October 31, 2020 00:00:00 GMT+09:00'`
2. ISO8601: `'2020-10-31T00:00:00.000+09:00'`

Veamos un ejemplo:

```js
//IETF-compliant RFC 2822: `'October 31, 2020 00:00:00 GMT+09:00'`
const rfc2822Date = new Date('October 31, 2020 00:00:00 GMT+09:00');
//ISO8601: `'2020-10-31T00:00:00.000+09:00'`
const iso8601Date = new Date('2020-10-31T00:00:00.000+09:00');

console.log('Fecha usando RFC2822:');
console.log(rfc2822Date.toString());
console.log('Fecha usando ISO8601:');
console.log(iso8601Date.toString());

console.log('¿Son la misma fecha?');
console.log(rfc2822Date.getTime() === iso8601Date.getTime());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Ahora ya sabemos establecer una fecha y hora de acuerdo a una zona horaria en específico, falta realizar el reloj de cuenta atrás.

En el código de tu pregunta se aprecia que deseas mostrar días, horas, minutos y segundos, entonces debemos calcular estos valores e ir actualizando cada cierto intervalo.

Vamos a elegir el intervalo de 1 segundo para realizar la actualización, es decir, cada 1 segundo realizamos el cálculo de días, horas, minutos y segundos.

Para ello vamos a crear una función que realice dichos cálculos, la llamaremos `updateClock()`.

Nuestra función recibirá la fecha, que hemos creado con anterioridad, como parámetro y calculará la cantidad de días, horas, minutos y segundos restantes para que el sistema en el que se ejecute el `script` alcance dicha fecha.

El cálculo es sencillo, usando el método [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getTime) del Objeto `Date`, podemos calcular la diferencia entre la fecha del sistema actual y la fecha que hemos calculado como futura.

Esta diferencia viene expresada en milisegundos, por lo tanto debemos calcular cuántos milisegundos equivalen a un día, a una hora, a un minuto y a un segundo.

- Un día equivale a `86400000` milisegundos.
- Una hora equivale a `3600000` milisegundos.
- Un minuto equivale a `60000` milisegundos.
- Un segundo equivale a `1000` milisegundos.

Por lo tanto para poner nuestro reloj en marcha debemos calcular estos valores a partir de la diferencia entre milisegundos de la fecha actual del sistema y la fecha límite.

De esta forma:

```js
const topDate = new Date('October 31, 2020 00:00:00 GMT+09:00');

const updateClock = (date) => {
  if(!date) return;
  let end = date.getTime();
  let now = Date.now();
  let diff = end - now;
  let days = Math.floor(diff / 86400000);
  diff = diff % 86400000
  let hours = Math.floor(diff / 3600000);
  diff = diff % 3600000;
  let minutes = Math.floor(diff / 60000);
  diff = diff % 60000;
  let seconds = Math.floor(diff / 1000);
  console.log(`Tiempo estimado: ${days} días, ${hours} horas, ${minutes} minutos, ${seconds} segundos.`);
}

updateClock(topDate);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Ya tenemos nuestra función, ahora sólo debemos crear el intervalo adecuado y cada vez que la página se cargue se ejecuta nuestra función y actualiza los campos, para ello debemos crear la estructura HTML que contendrá nuestro reloj.

```js
const topDate = new Date('October 31, 2020 00:00:00 GMT+09:00');

const updateClock = (date) => {
  if(!date) return;
  let end = date.getTime();
  let now = Date.now();
  let diff = end - now;
  let days = Math.floor(diff / 86400000);
  diff = diff % 86400000
  let hours = Math.floor(diff / 3600000);
  diff = diff % 3600000;
  let minutes = Math.floor(diff / 60000);
  diff = diff % 60000;
  let seconds = Math.floor(diff / 1000);
  document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = days;
  document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = hours;
  document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = minutes;
  document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;
}

// se llama a la función una vez para que pinte el resultado inmediatamente
updateClock(topDate);
// se hace uso de setInterval para cambiar el contador cada 1 segundo
setInterval(updateClock, 1000, topDate)
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div id="clock" class="clock">
  <div class="container">
    Días: <span id="days"></span>, Horas: <span id="hours"></span>, Minutos: <span id="minutes"></span>, Segundos: <span id="seconds"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Con esto ya tienes una forma de calcular el tiempo que falta para que se cumpla la fecha tope.

Solo faltaría verificar cuando la fecha se cumple para ocultar el reloj.

Esto lo podemos hacer usando una clase CSS para ocultarlo o incluso podemos removerlo del DOM: un reloj en cuenta regresiva sólo es válido mientras exista algo que contar.

Para removerlo del DOM, usaremos el método [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild), y con esto terminaremos.

Usaré un ejemplo básico y un contador de 6 segundos para mostrar cómo se remueve el elemento del DOM:

```js
const topDate = new Date(Date.now() + 6000);

const updateClock = (date) => {
  if(!date) return;
  let end = date.getTime();
  let now = Date.now();
  let diff = end - now;
  if(diff < 0) { // <- si el reloj ya mostró todo en cero, lo remuevo del DOM
    clearInterval(interval);
    let visor = document.getElementById('visor');
    document.getElementById('clock').removeChild(visor);
  } else {
    let days = Math.floor(diff / 86400000);
    diff = diff % 86400000
    let hours = Math.floor(diff / 3600000);
    diff = diff % 3600000;
    let minutes = Math.floor(diff / 60000);
    diff = diff % 60000;
    let seconds = Math.floor(diff / 1000);
    document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = days;
    document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = hours;
    document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = minutes;
    document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;
  }
}

// se llama a la función una vez para que pinte el resultado inmediatamente
updateClock(topDate);
// se hace uso de setInterval para cambiar el contador cada 1 segundo
const interval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000, topDate)
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  }
.visor {
  
}
```

```html
<div id="clock" class="clock">
  <div id="visor" class="container">
    Días: <span id="days"></span>, Horas: <span id="hours"></span>, Minutos: <span id="minutes"></span>, Segundos: <span id="seconds"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero que con esto tengas un poco más claro cómo lograr el objetivo.

Answer (score 6):

Bastaría con que indicaras la hora de Japón de este modo:

```js
var countDownDate = new Date('October 31, 2020 12:00:00 GMT+09:00');
console.log('Hora en UTC:',countDownDate);
```

Al aplicar GMT+09:00 (en el caso de Japón), Javascript tiene en cuenta la diferencia horaria, y el contadora terminaría el 31 de Octubre a las 03:00 (hora española).

Answer (score 6):

Puse el código lo más entendible posible. Inclusive un par de `console.log` para mostrar los inicios del algoritmo y su funcionamiento cada segundo.

```js
CronometroCuentaRegresiva('31 Oct 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0900', 'tableroCuentaRegresiva');

function CronometroCuentaRegresiva(fechaFinal, id) {
 console.log("Iniciando");

 var fechaFin = new Date(fechaFinal);

 //Definiendo tiempos:
 var _segundos = 1000; //Unidad basada en mili-segundos.
 var _minutos = _segundos * 60;
 var _horas = _minutos * 60;
 var _dias = _horas * 24;

 var cronometro;

 function mostrarRemanente() {
  console.log("actualizando cada segundo");
  var ahora = new Date();
  var diferencia = fechaFin - ahora;
  if (diferencia < 0) {

   clearInterval(cronometro);
   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '¡Ya pasó!';

   return;
  }
    
                //Estas son las variables del resultado
  var dias = Math.floor(diferencia / _dias);
  var horas = Math.floor((diferencia % _dias) / _horas);
  var minutos = Math.floor((diferencia % _horas) / _minutos);
  var segundos = Math.floor((diferencia % _minutos) / _segundos);

  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = dias + ' dias ';
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += horas + ' horas ';
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutos + ' minutos ';
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += segundos + ' segundos';
 }

 //Aqui la magia del intervalo que estará ejecutándose cada segundo:
 cronometro = setInterval(mostrarRemanente, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="tableroCuentaRegresiva">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Para poder lograrlo sólo tendrías que comparar fechas en milisegundos, el `if (distance < 0)` tendrías que cambiarlo a esto:

```
if (countDown === now) {
  // clearInterval
}
```

Comment: Pero no quedaria igual al dia en el que configure hay? ya que no usa GTM y quiero que sea en la hora y dia de ellos

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto un repositorio donde cree un contador hacia atrás, lo personalicé para lo que requieres, pero te lo explico enseguida

El repositorio se encuentra en https://github.com/orta93/reactClock

El archivo html que incluye el repositorio contiene dependencias de jQuery y la librería que llamé `reactClock`, funciona de esta forma

```
<!--Agregar un div con data-date donde coloques la fecha objetivo-->
<!--El atributo data-time debe tener la hora-->
<!--El atributo data-type indica el valor que requieres (Dia = d, Hora = h, Minutos = i, Segundos = s) -->
<!--Si data-type está vacío se muestran todos los elementos d h i s-->
<!--data-tz contiene la zona que requieres, en este caso es Asia/Tokio,
tambien puede ir vacía y tomara la hora del server-->
<!--data-min es un arreglo de datos en el que indicas el tiempo minimo para mostrar,
en este caso coloque d:60, por lo que se esperará 60 días para mostrarlo,
la nomenclatura usada es la misma del atributo date-type-->
<div class="reactClock" data-date="2020-10-31" data-time="00:00" data-type="" data-tz="Asia/Tokyo" data-min="d:60"></div>
```